# Writing a nested dictionary to a .txt file

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
{'Berlin': {'Type1': 96},
 'Frankfurt': {'Type1': 48},
 'London': {'Type1': 288, 'Type2': 64, 'Type3': 426},
 'Paris': {'Type1': 48, 'Type2': 96}}
```

I then want to write to a .txt file in the format

```
London
  Type1: 288
  Type2: 64
  Type3: 426

Paris
  Type1: 48
  Type2: 96

Frankfurt
  Type1: 48

Berlin
  Type1: 98
```

I've tried to use

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\capacity_report.txt", "w+")
f.write(json.dumps(mydict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

but this prints like this:

```
{
    "London": {
        "Type1": 288,
        "Type2": 64,
        "Type3": 426
     },
     "Paris": {
         "Type1": 48,
         "Type2": 96
     },
     "Frankfurt": {
         "Type1": 48
      },
      "Berlin": {
         "Type1": 98
      }
}
```

I'd like to have the punctuation and brackets removed. Is there a way to do this I can't see?

Comment: Python version? I don't understand exactly what do you want, filter entries where key is '\n'?

Comment: @Tzomas: that part is now removed.

Comment: The desired output looks almost like YAML.

Comment: I've removed the `\n` key-value issue for now, as that's a separate question (although you can trivially test for values not equal to 0 in the inner loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write out your dictionary manually. You are not trying to produce JSON here, and there is no point in using that module.

Iterate over the dictionary keys and values and write those out as lines. The `print()` function can be helpful here:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\capacity_report.txt", "w") as f:
    for key, nested in sorted(mydict.items()):
        print(key, file=f)
        for subkey, value in sorted(nested.items()):
            print('   {}: {}'.format(subkey, value), file=f)
        print(file=f)
```

The `print()` function takes care of newlines for us.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, this throws this error:                                                           print(key, file=f)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Can't see anything obvious causing that

Comment: @CEamonn: maybe you are using the old Python 2?

Comment: @cdarke apologies, I am using 2.7

Comment: @CEamonn: that is easily remedied as you can enable the Python 3 syntax on a per module basis with a `__future__` import.

Comment: @CEamonn: you can do this without the `__future__`  import too: the Python 2 statement can also direct the output to a file, but with the import your code is now also Python 3 compatible. If you are new to Python I’d actually strongly recommend you learn Python 3 and not bother with Python 2.

Comment: @CEamonn: the Python 2 only syntax is `print >> f, <thing to write to the file>`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks a lot, sorted. I'll leave 2 and look into 3

Answer (score 0):

If you use python 3.6 which preserve order on insert keys on dictionary, you can use something like this.

```
with open('filename.txt','w') as f:
    for city, values in my_dict.items():
        f.write(city + '\n')
        f.write("\n".join(["  {}: {}".format(value_key, digit) for value_key, digit in values.items()]) + '\n')
        f.write('\n')
```

Its works changing f.write for print. i hope this helps.

Comment: You are not writing enough newlines; remember that `print()` *adds* a newline each time that `file.write()` doesn’t.

Comment: True, I forgot to put the two new lines.

Comment: There is also a blank line missing, between each `city` section.